# Update a state passed through Link in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page - page1 with a link to page 2.

```
<Link to={{ pathname:`campaign/${data.id}`, state: data }}> View more </Link>
```

I'm passing a state to the new page in the `Link` element. In page 2 I make some change to the `data` that was passed. How do I update that changes on Page 1? Do I need to use Redux?

The router looks like this

```
<Route path="/" exact component = {HomePage}/>
<Route path="/campaign/:id" exact component = {Campaign}/>
```

Comment: Can you show us your react router `Route` setting?

Comment: @Chen-TaiHou I have updated the question.

Comment: page1 is Homepage and page2 is Campaign

Comment: So your goal is to pass new state to `Campaign`?

Comment: you don't need redux. how about you keep that state above both components (ie, the component where both those routes are being rendered)

Comment: I'm passing state to `Campaign` from `Homepage` through `Link`. State us updated in `Campaign`. I need that change to be updated in `Homepage`

Comment: @azium that is the confusion. `Campaign` is never rendered as a component. But redirected from `Homepage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ever need sibling components to share / modify the same piece of state, then that states needs to live in a common ancestor:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = { data: ... }
  updateData = newData => this.setState({ data: newData })
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route path="/" exact 
            component={props => 
              <HomePage {...props} data={this.state.data} updateData={this.updateData} />
            } 
          />
          <Route path="/campaign/:id" exact 
            component={props => 
              <Campaign {...props} data={this.state.data} updateData={this.updateData} />
            }
          />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: however you want. i'm not calling it in my example, I assume you are the one that wants to change that state somehow